# How to send a message or event into Server Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, networking

I am learning about Networking in Unity. I am confused on how can I send a message or event from client to server. I have these script already that successfully connect my client to server.

This is my server script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ServerNetwork : MonoBehaviour {

    void Start()
    {
        SetupServer();
    }

    // Create a server and listen on a port
    public void SetupServer()
    {

        NetworkServer.Listen(4444);
        NetworkServer.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnClientConnected);
        Debug.Log("Server is running");
    }

    void OnClientConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("Client connected");
        Debug.Log(netMsg.msgType);
    }
}
```

This is my client Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class ClientNetwork : MonoBehaviour {

    NetworkClient myClient;
    public bool isClientConnected = false;

    void Start()
    {
        SetupClient();
    }

    // Create a client and connect to the server port
    public void SetupClient()
    {
        myClient = new NetworkClient();
        myClient.RegisterHandler(MsgType.Connect, OnConnected);
        myClient.Connect("127.0.0.1", 4444);
        isClientConnected = true;
    }

    // client function
    public void OnConnected(NetworkMessage netMsg)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected to server");
    }
}
```

The Server Script is attached to "NetworkManager" Object on ServerScene

The Client Script is attached to "NetworkManager" Object on ClientScene

I have build ClientScene alone to run as a client, and running ServerScene inside editor

With these script, I can already connect the client into the server. From this, how can I communicate from client to server ?

the purpose here is to send real time score into the server from client every second.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `[SyncVars]` Attribute. In short what it does is it synchronize a variable from client to the server. Here is a simple example from `Unity3d` Documentation.

```
[SyncVar]
int health;

public void TakeDamage(int amount)
{
    if (!isServer)
        return;

    health -= amount;
}
```

another way to do this is by using custom `WebSocket` implementation for Unity3D. There a few very good ones in GitHub.Also please take a look at the documentation [Unity3d](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetStateSync.html)

Comment: I have tried the SyncVar, but it is said that there is no NetworkIdentity when calling a function. I have update the question. I am using different scene or Object for both script

Comment: @AdityoSetyonugroho in that case you should use Send() or SendBytes() methods on your client side. They are also easy to configure. I hope that helps.